# how to load the first n rows of a (large) JSON file in R?

Tags: json, r, rjsonio

I have a very large Json file that I would like to explore in R. The most natural way to do so would be to load into the workspace only a small part of the total json data, for instance the first 100 rows.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any option that allows me to do that with the leading Json packages for R such as RJSONIO. I can only load the entire dataset, which crashes my computer.

Any idea?
Many thanks!

Comment: take a look at `jsonlite::stream_in`

Comment: thanks! do you have a sample code in mind? Say I want to open the first 500 rows of my json file, and save them into a R file.

Comment: If it's minified, and don't care about anything after 500, you can just use `x<-readLines("myfile.json", n=500); x<-jsonlite::fromJSON(x)`, use `stream_in` if you want to do something to your entire data set piece by piece.

Comment: readLines didn't work properly because the json is not standard. I am loading the json right now using stream_in. No idea how to export the data to disk after that... also, I still cannot limit how many lines I want to load apparently... sob sob